# Fatal error: Class not found

Tags: php, mvc

Есть `mvc`-приложение со следующей структурой:

```
/app
       /controllers
                   /test.php
       /core
                   /App.php
                   /Controller.php
/public
       /index.php
```

`index.php`:

```
use App\Core\App;
require_once '../app/init.php';
$app = new App;
```

`App.php`:

```
namespace App\Core;
class App
{
    protected $controller = 'home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $url = $this->parseUrl();
        if (file_exists('../app/controllers/'.$url[0].'.php'))
        {
            $this->controller = $url[0];
            unset($url[0]);
        }
        require_once '../app/controllers/'.$this->controller.'.php';
        $this->controller = new $this->controller;
    }

    protected function parseUrl()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
            return $url = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    }
}
```

`test.php`:

```
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Core\Controller;
class Test extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'ok';die;
    }
```

При попытке обратиться по `domain.com/public/test` ошибка `Fatal error: Class 'test' not found in App.php on line 25` - на этапе создания нового объекта (`$this->controller = new $this->controller;`). Как дать понять функции, в каком `namespace` нужно создавать этот объект? Создать класс вот так

```
$this->controller = new 'App\Controllers\`.$this->controller
```

невозможно ("\" перед " ' ").

Без использования `namespace` ошибок нету.

Comment: Может быть полезно: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072352/instantiating-class-by-string-using-php-5-3-namespaces

Comment: Покажите ваш `test.php`

Comment: @rjhdby обновил вопрос

Comment: @rjhdby `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''\\App\\Controllers\\'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)`

Comment: `$class = '\\App\\Controllers\\'.$this->controller; $this->controller = new class();`

Comment: @rjhdby вот так сработало: `$class = '\\App\\Controllers\\'.$this->controller;
        $this->controller = new $class;`, спасибо